# Transfer of heat through a partly insulated copper rod

Tags: vacuum, thermal-conductivity

Say we have a copper rod with a length of $1\:\mathrm{m}$ and a diameter of $0,5\:\mathrm{cm}$ and we have attached one sphere with radius $R=0,5\mathrm{cm}$ to one of its ends and one identical sphere to its other end. Say also that the rod between the two spheres is surrounded by an air lock tube to which we apply vacuum so that the rod can only exchange heat with the environment through the spheres at its ends. Say we sink one of the spheres to water with a temperature of $40\:\mathrm{C}$. What will be the temperature of the other sphere after a while, if it is surrounded by air and why? Also, what would change if it was sank in water too?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. This is a wonderful site for physics questions and answers. We have some rules to keep the quality high. In particular, posts requesting a calculation is considered off-topic unless they show effort to solve the problem and indicate a specific aspect where you need help. Alternatively, you can ask a specific conceptual question.

Comment: Also, please use proper English punctuation. Put a space after each sentence and after each comma.

Comment: Well the conceptual answer is to consider the differential heat flows. Flow in  to the atmospheric sphere at temp of the water, and flow out to the atmosphere a standard temperature.
Perhaps the question is does the diameter of the connecting rod impact the heat flow down it. In which case the answer would be yes, and could be elaborated in general.

Comment: I'll answer this. But it'll take an hour or two to do so.

Comment: @Gert:  Nice - gets my upvote.

Comment: @Gert: Thank you for your answer. It was definitely helpful and detailed. More of a whole solution than just an answer.

Comment: @DanielSank: I am new to this site and unaware of how strict the formality rules regarding questions are. Will try to show my work on future problems from now on.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Thermal rod]

Consider the rod to be insulated over $x=0 \to x=L$. The left hand side is held at the constant temperature $T_0$. $T_{\infty}$ is the environment's temperature. The temperature profile and time evolution are described by [Fourier's heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Derivation_in_one_dimension):

$$\frac{\mathrm{\partial}T}{\mathrm{\partial}t}=\alpha \Big(\frac{\mathrm{\partial^2}T}{\mathrm{\partial}x^2}+\frac{\mathrm{\partial^2}T}{\mathrm{\partial}y^2}+\frac{\mathrm{\partial^2}T}{\mathrm{\partial}z^2}\Big)\tag{1}$$

To simplify things, consider that the rod is much longer than it is thick, so as an approximation we consider the temperature gradients in $y$ and $z$ drirections to be zero:

$$\frac{\mathrm{\partial}T}{\mathrm{\partial}y}=\frac{\mathrm{\partial}T}{\mathrm{\partial}z}=0$$

This reduces $(1)$ to:

$$\frac{\mathrm{\partial}T}{\mathrm{\partial}t}=\alpha \frac{\mathrm{\partial^2}T}{\mathrm{\partial}x^2}\tag{2}$$

This equation would solve to an expression for $T(x,t)$ but here we'll not concern ourselves with the *time evolution* (transient) but only with the *steady state* (thermal equilibrium). This means that $\frac{\mathrm{\partial}T}{\mathrm{\partial}t}=0$ and $(2)$ further reduces to:

$$\frac{\mathrm{\partial^2}T}{\mathrm{\partial}x^2}=0$$

We'll further simplify a bit by a simple substitution:

$$u(x)=T(x)-T_0 \implies \mathrm{\partial}u= \mathrm{\partial}T\implies \mathrm{\partial^2}u= \mathrm{\partial^2}T$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{\partial^2}u}{\mathrm{\partial}x^2}=0\tag{3}$$

**1. First case:**

> What will be the temperature of the other sphere after a while, if it is surrounded by air and why?

Firstly to solve $(3)$ we need *boundary conditions*.

The first one is:

$$T(0)=T_0\implies u(0)=0$$

For the second one we assume the right hand sphere loses heat through *convection only*. Mathematically, using Fourier and Newton's cooling law:

$$-kS\Big(\frac{\mathrm{d}T}{\mathrm{d}x}\Big)_{x=L}=hA[T(L)-T_{\infty}]$$
$$-kS\Big(\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}\Big)_{x=L}=hA[u(L)+T_0-T_{\infty}]$$
Where $k$ is the heat conductivity, $h$ the heat transfer coefficient, $S$ the cross section of the rod and $A$ the surface area of the right hand sphere.

$(3)$ solves easily to:
$$u(x)=c_1x+c_2$$
$c_1$ and $c_2$ are the integration constants. From the first boundary condition
$$u(0)=0\implies c_2=0$$
And with the second boundary condition:
$$-kSc_1=hA[c_1L+c_2+T_0-T_{\infty}]=hA[c_1L+T_0-T_{\infty}]$$
$$\implies c_1=-\frac{hA(T_0-T_{\infty})}{kS+hAL}$$
So we get:
$$\boxed{T(x)=T_0-\frac{hA(T_0-T_{\infty})}{kS+hAL}x}$$
Insert $x=L$ to get $T(L)$.

**2. Second case:**

> Also, what would change if it was sank in water too?

Here as a second boundary condition we assume:

$$T(L)=T_1\implies u(L)=T(L)-T_0=T_1-T_0$$
With:
$$u(x)=c_1x+c_2$$
$$u(0)=0\implies c_2=0$$
$$u(L)=T_1-T_0\implies T_1-T_0=c_1L\implies c_1=\frac{T_1-T_0}{L}$$
$$\boxed{T(x)=T_0+\frac{T_1-T_0}{L}x}$$